# Concatenar un numero indeterminado de columnas en una misma celda con formato separado por comas

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Dispongo de una hoja de cálculo  de Google donde cada fila tiene un número de columnas diferentes.

```
Fila 1 con texto en 3 columnas
Fila 2 con texto en 2 columnas
Fila 3 con texto en 5 columnas
```

¿Cómo podría concatenar en una celda vacía de cada fila los textos de las columnas indicadas en la misma, con formato separado con comas, con Google apps script ?
Por ejemplo, en la fila uno tengo 3 columnas con estos países: `España | Grecia | Argentina`. El código debe unir y escribir en la cuarta columna los tres textos de esta manera => `España,Grecia,Argentina`

Tengo este código pero solo sirve para cuando tenga 2 columnas a unir:

```
 function ConCat() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
 var col = sheet.getLastColumn
 for(var j=0; j<lr; i++){
 var values1 = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lr,1).getValues();  //Get vales for Column1
 var values2 = sheet.getRange(1, 2, lr,1).getValues();  //Get values for column 2
 var results = [];                               //Create a empty array to be filled concatenated elements
 

 // Add items to results
 for(var i=0; i<lr; i++){
 results[i] = [values1[i][0]+", "+values2[i][0]];
 }

//Post back to column 3 starting on row 2
sheet.getRange(1, 3, lr, 1).setValues(results);

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de leer cada columna por separado lee las tres columnas en una llamada y luego usa `Array.prototype.map` para concatenar los valores de cada fila usando `Array.prototype.join`.

Por ejemplo

```
function ConCat() {`

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
 var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
 var source = sheet.getRange(1,1,lr,3).getValues(); // Leer los valores de las columnas A, B y C
 var results = source.map(row => row.join(', '); // Concatenar los valores de cada fila

 sheet.getRange(1, 4, lr, 1).setValues(results); // Escribir los valores en la columna D

}}
```